# Sub-steps setting for Simulation Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

In the Blender 4.0 online reference, there is this mention in the Simulation Nodes section:

> *In the Node Editor the inputs can be renamed, shuffled and removed. This is also the place where sub-steps can be defined for a simulation.*

[Source](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/simulation/simulation_zone.html#properties)

Where is the sub-step settings for Simulation Nodes in Blender 4.0?